# Stackexchange.Redis Channel Subscription Patterns (exclusions)

Tags: c#, redis, glob, stackexchange.redis

I'm attempting to write up a channel pattern for a Redis subscription such that, when my application is in Debug mode, I subscribe to all channels ending in `_dev`, but when not in debug mode, I subscribe to all channels that specifically *don't* end in `_dev`.  My channels look something like: `CommandChannel_<id>` or `CommandChannel_<id>_dev`

I understand that, according to the documentation, "all glob-style patterns are valid", and so I've written up a pattern that I feel like should do the trick:

```
string subBase = "CommandChannel_"
redisSubscription.SubscribeAsync(subBase + "*" + (DEBUG ? "_dev": "!(_dev)"), async (channel, message) =>
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

What I'm finding is that, when in DEBUG mode, my subscription works fine - I correctly "catch" all messages over any channel matching the pattern of `CommandChannel_<id>_dev`.  But when I change the application to not be in DEBUG mode, my subscription doesn't catch anything despite definitely publishing to appropriate channels (`CommandChannel_<id>`).  As I understand it, `!(_dev)` should exclude any channels ending in `_dev`, but allow all other channels that I expect.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis itself does not support that usage; [relevant docs](https://redis.io/commands/psubscribe):

> Supported glob-style patterns:
>
> - `h?llo` subscribes to `hello`, `hallo` and `hxllo`
> - `h*llo` subscribes to `hllo` and `heeeello`
> - `h[ae]llo` subscribes to `hello` and `hallo`, but not `hillo`

Exclusions are not mentioned, and from testing in redis-cli: do not work. Suggestions:

1. use separate servers/ports for prod and dev - not patterns
2. use an active pattern (not the lack of a pattern) for all logical tiers/tenants

Comment: Damn, this was what I was afraid of.  https://redis.io/topics/pubsub documentation is what I quoted mentioning that "**all** the glob-style patterns are valid" and was what I was depending on to be accurate.